# How to show and hide a view on header without affecting the below ViewPager?

Tags: android

In my requirement, I have an action bar at the top. Below action bar, I have another header. On that header, I have a button. Below that header, the remaining content is view pager. Now when I click the button on the header, some list of textviews should display overlapping the below viewpager. And again when I click on the button those text view should hide. Now my problem is view pager is getting affected when showing and displaying the top header text views.

Below is my image:

[image]

Code:

```
PagerLayout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Total"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"


                app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />


        </LinearLayout>




        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/black"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:background="@color/calculate_grey"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10px"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="Text 1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10px"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="Text 2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10px"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="Text 3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:background="@color/calculate_grey"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>





</RelativeLayout>

Fragmemt:

public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
    Button button1, button2;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //returning our layout file
        //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pagerlayout, container, false);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager, true);

        tv1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv3);

        button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // do something
                button1.setVisibility(v.GONE);
                tv1.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                tv2.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                tv3.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                button2.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // do something
                button1.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                tv1.setVisibility(v.GONE);
                tv2.setVisibility(v.GONE);
                tv3.setVisibility(v.GONE);
                button2.setVisibility(v.GONE);
            }
        });


        return v;
    }




}
```

Comment: You can just overlap both of them, and can put the header code below pager code, so that z-index of header can be greater than that of pager

Comment: Hi Sorry I didn't get you...can you please give some sample

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:visibility = "invisible" instead of gone. And same in the java also instead of setting it gone set it as invisible.